# Give second or fourth column right side border using css in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I just want to give second and fourth `<td >` right side border ...

as you can see I have following table:

```
<table class="secondtd">
  <tr>
     <td> Name </td>
     <td> Class </td>
     <td> RollNo </td>
     <td> Batch </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried something like this in css

```
.secondtd  td+td {
  border-right:solid 1px red;
}
```

but not work for me .. **I am using IE .**

Comment: where do you use `.secondtd` class? I don't see in your html

Comment: typo mistak when writing question ..... as you can check table i here made just for example not the real one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign the class two the 2nd and 4th element of the tables:

```
 <td class="secondborder"> </td>
```

Or you could use `nth-child`:

```
td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(4) {
 border-right:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekHQf/

Which would select the 2nd and 4th element. If you only have 4 td's you could use `even`:

```
td:nth-child(even) {
  border-right:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekHQf/1/

**Edit**:

From the comments to do this with a class applied:

```
.secondtd td:nth-child(2) {
  border-right:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but not working .secondtd  nth-child(2)
 {
 border-right:thick double #ff0000;
}

Comment: @rahularyansharma you need the colon, it's :nth-child(2)

Comment: @rahularyansharma I have posted a few JSFiddles for you to look at, hope this helps.

Comment: you are not using class name anywhere .... i have many tables on that page so i need to include class name as well.. am i rt ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma you can proceed it with .class. For instance .secondtd td:nth-child(2) { ... }

Comment: actually this worked for me .....secondtd :first-child + td,
.secondtd :first-child + td + td + td {
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}

Answer (score 3):

There are three basic options.

1) Set a class on the cells and use a simple class selector. Dull, but works on all CSS-enabled browsers.

2) Use the `:first-child` pseudoclass together with the sibling operator `+`:

```
.secondtd :first-child + td,
.secondtd :first-child + td + td + td {
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}
```

Works on all reasonably modern browsers, even including IE 7 (but not IE 6) in “Standards Mode”. Not too clumsy I think, but if it were 42nd column instead of 2nd and 4th, it would become awkward.

3) Use `:nth-child(...)` pseudoclass:

```
.secondtd td:nth-child(2),
.secondtd td:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}
```

Works on modern browsers, including IE 9 (but not earlier versions) in “Standards Mode”.

In this special case, you could use a shorter selector list, because in the range of column numbers here, 2 and 4 are the only that correspond to `2n` (where `n` implicitly takes all nonnegative integer values 0, 1, 2,...):

```
.secondtd td:nth-child(2n) {
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try applying the class element to only the places you want to see it, i.e. in the  tags.

```
<table>

 <tr>
   <td> Name </td>
   <td class="secondborder"> Class </td>
   <td> RollNo </td>
   <td class="secondborder"> Batch </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: sorry but i don't want to give each td style ... may be using css3 it can be done using single statement in css .....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css `nth-child`:

```
td:nth-child(even) {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will select every second element

Answer (score 0):

use `nth-child` css selector to set the corresponding td styles.

```
td:nth-child(2) ,td:nth-child(4)
{
    border-right:solid 1px red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkppu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth-child selector with either `:nth-child(even)` or `:nth-child(2n)` to add it to every other td. If you need to support older browsers, you can use jQuery to add a class of `even` to the td's and add that to the css.

**css**

```
.secondtd td.even,
.secondtd td:nth-child(even) {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

**js**

```
// jQuery fallback
$('.secondtd td:nth-child(even)').addClass('even');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/gsU4K/